# how to search and reset my following array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Actully array1 is my default array. but i provide facility to purchase readingOrder from my site. now if some casino_id 78 is purchase readingOrder 1 than i have to keep it in first position.It's actual readingOrder is 4.
Consider  readingOrder = rank and id=casino_id.

so basically array1 is my default array.array2 is purchase order and i want result to like array3 from this two array.

```
$array1 = Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 76
                [readingOrder] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 81
                [readingOrder] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
                [readingOrder] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 80
                [readingOrder] => 4
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 82
                [readingOrder] => 5
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 83
                [readingOrder] => 6
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 84
                [readingOrder] => 7
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 85
                [readingOrder] => 8
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 86
                [readingOrder] => 9
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 87
                [readingOrder] => 10
            )

    )
```

Secon array:-

```
$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 1
            [casino_id] => 78
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 4
            [casino_id] => 76
        )

)
```

third one:-

```
$array3 = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
                [readingOrder] => 1
            )


        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 81
                [readingOrder] => 2
            )


        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 80
                [readingOrder] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 76
                [readingOrder] => 4
            )


        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 82
                [readingOrder] => 5
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 83
                [readingOrder] => 6
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 84
                [readingOrder] => 7
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 85
                [readingOrder] => 8
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 86
                [readingOrder] => 9
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 87
                [readingOrder] => 10
            )

    )
```

Comment: Can you include  actual array (as per php)  in question

Comment: 1. get the keys of second array 2. filter the array 1 which do not have keys of second array 3. change the keys of array 4. merge it (its almost midnight here ).. I will answer it if nobody answer till tomorrow .. good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this would work in your case with a mixture of [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). Check inline comments for details.

```
// get (rank => casino_id) type array from array2 using array functions.
$array3 = array_combine(array_column($array2, 'rank'), array_column($array2, 'casino_id'));
//similar type from array1
$array4 = array_combine(array_column($array1, 'readingOrder'), array_column($array1, 'id'));

$temp = $finalArr = array();
//push only if the value is present in high priority array (array3).
foreach ($array4 as $key => $val) {
  $temp[$key] = $array3[$key] ? $array3[$key] : $array4[$key];
}

//finally modify the array according to original key=> value type.
foreach ($temp as $k => $v) {
  $finalArr[] = array(
    'id' => $v,
    'readingOrder' => $k,
  );
}
```

Comment: I've checked this for only 4 array values in $array1, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Can we remove value of array1 which is already available in array2. just for remove duplicate id form final array.

Comment: I don't think you'll get duplicate values in final array as we insert uniquely into temp. Thanks for the update though, missed the typo. Just don't understand the reason for downvote(TWIMC) for the accepted answer.

Comment: I am also surprised. why people downvote the accepted answer.

Comment: I got it, I can take a proper look tomorrow.